# Limit of sum of the series

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What would be the sum of following ?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+3)^{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n+n)^{2}}\right]$$

I tried to turn it into integral :

$\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{(1+\frac{r}{n})^{2}}\frac{1}{n^{2}} $ but 
I can't figure out how to deal with $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$

Comment: For large values it will be $0$ i think

Comment: The sum is asymptotic to $\log 2/n$, isn't it?

Comment: I really don't know the final answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ so what is an upper bound for:

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\dots\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}?$$

By the way, you could see this as an integral limit if you wrote it as:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac k n\right)^2}$$

But: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac k n\right)^2}\to\int_{0}^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}=\frac12$$

So with the extra $\frac{1}{n}$, you can determine what the limit will be...

Comment: Thanks, didn't think this approach.

Comment: excuse me but isnt this supposed to be $\int_{1}^2 \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}$ ?

Comment: Whoops, yes, will fix when I get to a computer. @Agawa001

Comment: Also, the range was wrong - should be 0 to 1.

Comment: mm yes i used to be much focused on the container than bounds of integral. but what you did is nice trick

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}0\le\lim_{n\to\infty} [\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+3)^{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{(n+n)^{2}}]\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}0\le\lim_{n\to\infty} [\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+3)^{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{(n+n)^{2}}]\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n}{(1+\frac1n)^2}$$
$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty} [\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+3)^{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{(n+n)^{2}}]\le0$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} [\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+3)^{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{(n+n)^{2}}]=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{j=}^{\infty}1/j^2$ converges by the Cauchy condensation test so $0<\sum_{j=n}^{j=2 n}1/j^2 < \sum_{j=n}^{\infty}1/j^2$ which $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$